# Increase static class variable in a constructor

Tags: php

Hi I've got the following simple problem:

I'd like to increase a static class variable each time an instance of an object is created. I've tried this:

```
class task
{
    static $tid = 0;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->tid++;
    }   
}
```

This returns the following error message:

```
Notice: Undefined property: task::$tid in ... on line ...
```

How to do this correctly? Thx in advance :)

**EDIT:**

Sorry, it is clear that this approach cant work, cause the static keyword indicates that the property is not bound to an instance, thus -> doesnt work. But how to do this correctly?

`$tid++` doesnt work. Error: undefined variable.

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.properties).

Comment: As it's static, `$this->` won't work because that refers to the instance

Comment: @Mark Baker, @axiac, yeah you're right. It is obvious now that -> wont work. `$tid++` does not work either though :( It says `Undefined variable`. But how to do it correctly. In C++ you could write `setTid(tid+1)` assuming that function is defined. However it is not obvious to me now what the CORRECT solution is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.properties):

> Static properties cannot be accessed through the object using the arrow operator ->. Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be initialized using a literal or constant before PHP 5.6; expressions are not allowed.

There is however a way. You must use `self` keyword:

```
class Task
{
    static $tid = 0;

    function __construct()
    {
        self::$tid++;
    }   
}

new Task();
new Task();

echo Task::$tid;
```

will output `2`

Answer (score 3):

The following will increase the static each time you create a new class instance. You must use the `self` keyword. You can then access the value using `$var::$tid` or create a function to return the value. The following will return 1122. Of course, as Nordenheim points out, you don't need the getter fn if $tid is `public static`. If it is `private static`, the getter would allow access to it.

```
class task
{
    public static $tid = 0;

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$tid++;
    }   

    public function gettid(){
    return self::$tid;
    }

}

$a = new task;
echo ($a->gettid());
echo $a::$tid;

$b = new task;
echo ($b->gettid());
echo $b::$tid;
```

Comment: Do you realize that it's incredibly absurd to implement a getter which returs `self::$tid` when you can actually do `task::$tid` outside the class? It's like attaching a pen to a manequin hand and control the manequin hand to write text in your notebook.

Comment: @Nordenheim - I am only showing the different methods for referencing vars. If tid was a private static, this would be your getter. Who is to say that any variable should or shouldn't be public or private.